# How to Append new data to already existing hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive

How to append the records to existing partitioned Hive table?
For example I have existing external Table called "ip_country" and dataset is testdata1. If dataset grows say like my dataset in next day is testdata1 and testdata2 then how to append new data i.e.., "testdata2" to "ip_country" hive table.

Comment: try http://hortonworks.com/blog/four-step-strategy-incremental-updates-hive/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be achieved in couple of ways (Purely depends on your requirement)

1. If you don't bother about overwriting the existing records in the partition, (I mean you don't have a big history data, say 10 yrs data), then Insert Overwrite might fit.

> INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tablename1 [PARTITION (partcol1=val1,
>   partcol2=val2 ...) [IF NOT EXISTS]] select_statement1 FROM
>   from_statement;

2. If you don't bother about duplicates in the partition, then Insert Into might fit (Honestly I wudn't prefer to have duplicate records).

> INSERT INTO TABLE tablename1 [PARTITION (partcol1=val1, partcol2=val2
>   ...)] select_statement1 FROM from_statement;

3. If you have history data plus Incremental data, then History data can be inserted once and the incremental data(based on the frequency that you choose daily/weekly/fortnightly basis) can be inserted using a Insert Overwrite

Comment: I dont want to overwrite history data again. I just want to insert incremental records without disturbing existing data. In this case which insert overwrite wont work for me.

Comment: A quick query. So by incremental data you refer to the previous day data alone rite ??

Comment: Yes. Data which is coming in future.

Comment: Fine. Since, you need a daily refresh (previous day alone), then assuming your table to be partitioned on date column, then on every day refresh, new partition with new data is what we are looking at. So INSERT INTO will be suffice. And INSERT OVERWRITE also would do the same as INSERT INTO (nothing to overwrite), since it is a daily refresh (1 day alone).

Comment: My usecase is like this, I have table called Country_IP and it has two columns like IP_Address and Country_Name. Partition is done by country_name. For example : On Day1 Dataset1 has 3000 records and on Day2 Dataset2 contains 50 records. When I do INSERT INTO its getting appending and count is 7000 records. If I do INSERT OVERWRITE then 3050 records are coming but its deleting the records first and comibing both records. Is there any solution records should delete while  doing INSERT OVERWRITE ?

Comment: Hmm.. As far as I see there are only 3 solutions to your usecase
1. If INSERT INTO is being used, then you have to deal with duplicate records, Since your partition column is country.
2. If INSERT OVERWRITE is used, (which I think is best for your usecase) then deletion and then insertion will happen. Moreover there won't be much overhead in the deletion of records and then insertion.
3. If you are not satisfied with both of the above things, then you must bring in date column into table and make it as a partition. In that case, you can use INSERT INTO.
Hope this helps you :)