# How to safely append data into a partitioned Hive table?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a production hive table partitioned by `date`. New data are generated hourly, and I need to merge the new data into the hive table.
In case there're duplicate data insertion requests or data overlap among hourly requests, I want to perform dedup to each partition whenever I update it.

I reviewed the answer to [How to Append new data to already existing hive table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211878/how-to-append-new-data-to-already-existing-hive-table)
, but still have some confusions:

1. How should I merge the new data pieces into the existing partition?
   I mean, should I create a tmp table for the new data, pull existing data into the tmp table, make dudup and `OVERWRITE` back the partition of the production table?
2. Is it possible `"dirty read"` could occur during the overwriting of the partition of the production hive table? Is there any solution to this?
   I'm wondering if there's anything like atomic `RENAME`.

Comment: Hi @mazaneicha, I know `move` is atomic. I'm just not sure if it's safe if I `move` (or `rename`) a staging partition directory to be within the table data directory, just using HDFS command, but not Hive command (sounds like bypassing Hive).